# Dynamic DNS Security

Tags: ip, dyndns

I have some clients whose IP changes every day and static IP is not an option for them.

If I have them install a Dynamic DNS client, and then in my application .htaccess file refer to that Dynamic DNS domain, does that pose any security issue for my application?

So to summarize does using Dynamic DNS domains in my .htaccess files pose any security related threats to my application?

Comment: Would appreciate if any info please.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand this, you want to add your clients IP addresses to the whitelist of your application and you want to switch to DynDNS because the IP addresses change every day.
So you want to assign each client a different domain and whitelist each of those domains, is that correct?

The obvious attack vector here would be hijacking a domain and pointing it to a malicous machine other than the clients machine using the DynDNS service.
If you manage to register the DynDNS client on the clients machine without exposing any login information regarding the domain that could be stolen or lost then this should be safe. But I currently do not see how you would be able to register the client for your domains DynDNS without having the credentials stored somewhere on this machine.